# Error on protected sheet

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have macro enabled workbook. Both Workbook and sheets are password protected.

Basically, I have 2 sheets. First "crater" which has a drop down list and buttons.

Second, "`Uno`" which has buttons again( Its a hidden sheet)

Button 1 on crater page task is to just copy the "`Uno`" sheet and create a new sheet. All tasks are working fine.

But my problem is, when I create a child sheet and save and close the workbook.

Next time, As soon as I open workbook I get an "error '1004'. You cannot use the command on protected sheet. You must first unprotect sheet" .

I would like to know, Where can I use the code to unprotect sheet in this case?

I am confused, please help

Answer (score 1):

Use the command `Worksheet("Your_Sheet_Name").Unprotect` if you have a password you need to add it as well `Worksheet("Your_Sheet_Name").Unprotect(Password)`

You can have it in the **Workbook Open** and it will unlock the worksheet. However, then all the users can modify this worksheet as well.